# Minimizing SWAP usage, but Cache is forcing Ubuntu to use SWAP

Tags: ssd, swap, cache

I have a 128 GB SSD (with DRAM cache) and 1 TB HDD. I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 in the SSD (**/, /home, swap [8GB]** in SSD and data in HDD). My PC has 8 GB RAM. I have reduced **swappiness** to 20 from 60 to minimize the write operation on SSD. Even after reducing it, I often see swap is being used even though RAM is consumed only 20-25%. This might happen more often during file transfer from external HDD to internal HDD. In *system monitor* it shows "cache" size around 4 GB. Is this the reason for my SWAP getting used even though I have enough free space in RAM? Here is an image of that scenario-
[image: SWAP being used]

How would I solve this to reduce write operation on my SSD? Thanks.

Comment: One way: you could simply turn swap off if your RAM usage is consistenly low. Ubuntu runs fine without any swap at all...if you have enough RAM.

Comment: Swap really doesn't have any direct relationship with how much memory is used. Swap is about the system moving "least recently used pages" to/from RAM to swap (or /swapfile). If you remove swap, your system will freeze/hang if it runs out of RAM. By changing vm.swappiness to 20, there's a chance that smaller RAM systems may spend a lot of time spinning their wheels, trying to manage everything in RAM. (This is just a general description... so hard-core swap experts... please don't beat me up :-) )

Comment: Unused RAM gets allocated to buff/cache (as seen in `free -h`), and when you're copying files, that's where you want it. Lastly, modern SSD's DON'T wear out due to swapping. They use a technique called "wear leveling" to make sure that swap doesn't cause problems like it did on early SSD's.